# Setting up layout of calculator buttons on android

Tags: android, android-layout, padding, android-layout-weight

I have just started learning Android. To start with,I just wanted to create a Calculator application similar to what we get in stock android phones. I used the following layouts:

1. Vertical Layout contining two rows which are:

   - Text view to display the result as a horizontal layout
   - Horizontal layout with two columns:

     - Table layout containing buttons 0-9, '.' and '=' with 3 buttons in each row
     - Table layout containing DEL, + , - , x and / buttons.

I want proper alignment of 4 rows of the first table layout and 5 rows of the second table layout. Shall I remove the padding space? Or do I need to manually set the minimum size of the buttons? Are the layouts set by me correct?

`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:text="7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button7" />

                <Button
                    android:text="8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button8" />

                <Button
                    android:text="9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:elevation="0dp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:text="4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button4" />

                <Button
                    android:text="5"
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <Button
                    android:text="6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button6" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button1" />

                <Button
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button2" />

                <Button
                    android:text="3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button3" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:text="."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
                    android:minHeight="48dp" />

                <Button
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button0" />

                <Button
                    android:text="="
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonequals"/>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:text="DEL"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDelete" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:text="/"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonDivide" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:text="x"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:text="+"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonPlus" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:text="-"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ocwq.png)

[Required layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sennl.png)

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code can do the job i guess,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:andriod="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/resultview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/resultview"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#000000">



                <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/row1"
                    android:background="#000000">
                    <Button
                        android:text="7"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button7" />
                    <Button
                        android:text="8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:id="@+id/button8" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="9"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button9"
                        android:elevation="0dp" />

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/row2"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/row1">

                    <Button
                        android:text="4"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button4" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="5"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="6"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button6" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="100dp">

                    <Button
                        android:text="1"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button1" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="2"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button2" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="3"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button3" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000">

                    <Button
                        android:text="."
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
                        android:minHeight="48dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="0"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/button0" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="="
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonequals"/>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:minHeight="80dp">

                    <Button
                        android:text="DEL"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:minHeight="80dp">

                    <Button
                        android:text="/"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:minHeight="80dp">

                    <Button
                        android:text="x"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:minHeight="60dp">

                    <Button
                        android:text="+"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:text="-"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you can use [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) for that view

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</GridLayout>
```

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677

http://sampleprogramz.com/android/gridlayout.php

Comment: If we use GridLayout, the symbols (right most with 5 rows ) column in the display wont match with the numbers having 4 rows, the desired layout [Required Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sennl.png) cannot be obtained.Please help, what to do?

Comment: you can create seperate layout for (right most with 5 rows )

Answer (score 1):

You could either set the height of the buttons, or add padding.

BTW, a parent with height of `wrap_content` and children with height `match_parent` is legal, I suppose, but a bit odd. I'd give the children either a fixed height, or `wrap_content` with a sufficient padding to get the look that you want.

Comment: Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek. Giving fixed height to the children works. Will it work on every screen size?

Answer (score 1):

Go for Custom ViewGroup and Custom Views as child. You will have much more flexibility and control over performance also learn for your good..

Btw, Creating custom components are easy.

Thanks